# Swift Interesting NSExceptionError When Passing Data Forward

Tags: swift, xcode, parameter-passing, nsbundle, nsexception

I have a really simple question here that I cannot manage to solve. This code works perfectly fine, leading me to the fifth view controller.

```
@objc func OnbtnPlusTouched()

{
    let uivc = storyboard!.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "FifthViewController")
    navigationController!.pushViewController(uivc, animated: true)

}
```

However, I want to pass the data locationName from this viewcontroller to the next one. Thus I used this code segment:

```
@objc func OnbtnPlusTouched()

{
    let vc = FifthViewController(nibName: "FifthViewController", bundle: nil)
    vc.locationName = locationName
    navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
}
```

But now I am getting this error as soon as I enter this function in my app:

> libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type
>
> > NSException and Terminating app due to uncaught exception
> >     'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Could not load NIB in
> >     bundle: 'NSBundle

I would appreciate any help, thank you!

Comment: Why did you need to change how the view controller is created just because you want to set a property? Why not do a typecast instead?

Comment: @JoakimDanielson that's because this is the only way I know to pass a data forward in this situation :-(

Comment: Did you also move the view and controller from the storyboard to a XIB?

Comment: @Willeke I didn't touch anything in the storyboard, I only added titles to my storyboards some time ago but that's it. I don't understand how the above code can work but the below one can't.

Comment: You can't load a view controller from a nib if the nib doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this instead

```
@objc func OnbtnPlusTouched() {
    guard let uivc = storyboard!.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "FifthViewController") as? FifthViewController else {
         return 
    }
    uivc.locationName = locationName
    navigationController!.pushViewController(uivc, animated: true)
}
```

Comment: You shouldn't force unwrap `storyboard` here. With a optional chaining you can check for both cases in one statement